# Making a Wordpress plugin that "connects" to the already existing woocommerce plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to get the price at the top of my screen here to show up in the shopping cart when i push the add to cart button…

As to how far I have come in the progress, I have written jQuery and js functions for making the price and demonstration change on user input. My current attempt is using ajax to send the price to the server-side and then send the price to the woocommerce add to cart. but it doesn’t work, so i am asking for some tips.

PS: I am new to this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh4PQ.jpg

I have tried this code:

```
function calculatePrice() {
    var input = $("#input").val();
    var height = parseFloat($("#height-select").val());
    var length = (input.length * height) / 10;
    var price = length * 2;
    var formattedPrice = price.toFixed(2);

    return formattedPrice;
  }

  function sendUpdatedPriceToServer() {
    let updatedPrice = calculatePrice(); // Assume this function calculates the price based on current input values

    // Your existing AJAX code to send the updated price to PHP
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: bannerCalcData.ajax_url,
      data: {
        action: "update_calculated_price",
        security: bannerCalcData.ajax_nonce,
        price: updatedPrice,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  }

 // JavaScript function to update the product price
  function updatePrice() {
    var formattedPrice = calculatePrice();

    $("form.cart").data("calculatedPrice", formattedPrice);

    // Update the price on the WooCommerce product page
    var priceElement = $("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").find("bdi");

    // Remove the existing price
    priceElement.empty();

    // Add the currency symbol and the new price
    priceElement.append(
      '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>' + formattedPrice
    );

    $("#calculated_price").val(formattedPrice);

    console.log("Calculated Price:", formattedPrice);

    // Send the updated price to the server
    sendUpdatedPriceToServer();
  }
```

in the php i have this:

```
function update_calculated_price() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_nonce', 'security' );

    if ( isset( $_POST['price'] ) ) {
        $price = floatval( $_POST['price'] );
        // Save the price in the session, or any other preferred storage method
        WC()->session->set( 'calculated_price', $price );
        wp_send_json_success( array( 'message' => 'Price updated successfully.' ) );
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'message' => 'Error updating the price.' ) );
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_update_calculated_price', 'update_calculated_price');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_calculated_price', 'update_calculated_price');

function banner_calc_shortcode() {
html etc

}
```